# Is there a way to trigger useFocusEffect every time the screen gets focused with no dependencies at all?

Tags: react-native

I have been reading react native documentation and some other posts about this topic and it seems there is no way to trigger an action on react native every time a screen is rendered. I was planning to fetch data that might eventually change so i need to fetch that data everytime the user opens up that screen.

UseFocusEffect should indeed work for this matter but it only happens to trigger once. Here is one of the multiple chunks of code i have tried so far:

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
           //fetch data
        };
        loadData();
    }, [])
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want it to happen on *every* render, you could just call `loadData()` outside of any `useFocusEffect` or `useCallback` -- just call it before returning the rendered data. **However**, this is likely to cause an infinite loop, assuming that `loadData` does something that will also cause a re-render. So, this seems like an A/B problem. Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to accomplish by triggering an effect on every render, someone could suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 8):

For your solution, there might be two ways to solve.

Way 1: By using isFocused from react-navigation/native.

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
     console.log('In inFocused Block', isFocused);
     loadData();
  }
}, [isFocused]);

const loadData = async () => { };
```

Way 2: By using Navigation Listener

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('In Navigation Add Listener Block');
      loadData();
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

In both ways, it will render every-time when the page is load or Get focused!

Comment: Even if this works, why does `useFocusEffect` not work?